# Usage of node-sass-jspm-importer paths configuration

Tags: node.js, sass, gulp, jspm

I'm trying to get my head around this sass importer:
https://github.com/idcware/node-sass-jspm-importer

I'm not entirely certain I'm trying to use it correctly.

I'm trying to use the example of using it to import font-awesome.
The GitHub page provides the following example

```
gulp.task('build-sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('src/sass/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass({
            errLogToConsole: true,
            functions: sassJspm.resolve_function('/lib/'),
            importer: sassJspm.importer
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'));
});
```

In this example I'm uncertain how much of a bearing this section has:

> gulp.src('src/sass/*.scss')

How does this path make any sense when the SASS/SCSS files are to be imported from JSPM Packages which would have paths like:

> jspm_packages/npm/font-aweesome@4.6.3/scss

The lib folder in this section

> functions: sassJspm.resolve_function('/lib/'),

Should that be /jspm_packages/ since in the documentation it specifies

> Where /lib/ is the path to your jspm_packages folder in your document
>   root.

In which case why did they not just specify jspm_packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was thinking about this all wrong.  One of the things I was missing was that with SASS/SCSS you can use import directives.  As such rather than import many generated css files it makes more sense to have the SASS compiler/importer produce one single CSS File.

So I created a single SCSS file that was outside of my JSPM_Packages folder in src called SCSS.

In this SCSS file I could then place the following code

```
$fa-font-path: jspm_resolve("font-awesome/fonts/"); 
@import "jspm:font-awesome/scss/font-awesome";
```

The line in the gulp file:

```
gulp.src('src/scss/*.scss')
```

Can then find this single SCSS File and from there work out how to import all the SCSS Files for Font-Awesome through the JSPM_Package folder structure.  A single main CSS file was then placed in the destination directory which contained the css from font-awesome.

Which in my case where I'm using ASP.NET Core looks like this:

```
.pipe(gulp.dest('./wwwroot/css'));
```

The functions line needed to be set to jspm_packages

```
functions: sassJspm.resolve_function('/jspm_packages/'),
```

I'm not sure why they have it as lib in their documentation - maybe this was an old JSPM configuration?